# nasm assembly sys_execve /bin/sh

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, shellcode

I'm trying to trigger sys_execve (X86_64).

```
section .data
file db "/bin/sh",0

section .text
global _start

_start:

mov rax, 59
mov rdi, file
lea rsi, [file] 
mov rdx, 0
syscall
```

It gives **Segmentation fault**

What am I doing wrong?

I even tried to put it in a C source:

```
int main(void)
{
char shellcode[] =
"\xb8\x3b\x00\x00\x00"
"\x48\xbf\xd0\x00\x60\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00"
"\x48\x8d\x34\x25\xd0\x00\x60"
"\x00"
"\xba\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x0f\x05";

(*(void (*)()) shellcode)();

return 0;
}
```

This also gives me a Segmentation fault...

Comment: `lea rsi, [file]` is wrong.

Comment: How about spamming some more tags?

Comment: @Jester: I thought that execve needs as second parameter the pointer of the string?

Comment: You [thought wrong](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execve).

Comment: well, can you give me a hint? I put rsi to 0 and it won't work. I tried this too: https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/original/96/83/63565574166578/0/635655741665789683.jpg and the shell won't be spawn...

Comment: You need to pass an array of arguments, with the end denoted by a NULL.

Comment: [How to pass argv arguments to execv in asm on 64-bit (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047512) has a more detailed answer.  (That question isn't asking for shellcode.  The answers here aren't shellcode either, despite the tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
section .data
file db '/bin/sh',0
file_arg db 'sh',0
argv dq file_arg, 0

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov     rax, 59
mov     rdi, file
mov     rsi, argv
mov     rdx, 0
syscall
```

Comment: Just for the record, this is not shellcode.  It contains `0` bytes, isn't position-independent, and has the data in a separate section from the code.  You'd have to rewrite everything except the `syscall` instruction to get something you could hexdump into a C string and call via a function pointer, let alone something you could actually inject into a `strcpy` buffer overflow in a program with an executable stack and no stack-cookie hardening.

Answer (score 1):

You are causing the kernel to dereference the string `/bin/sh` as a pointer by loading it's address into `rsi`.

Just pass an empty environment and arguments by setting `dx` and `si` to 0.

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
  mov rax, 59
  mov rdi, file  // *filename
  mov rsi, 0     // *argv
  mov rdx, 0     // *envp
  syscall

section .data
  file db "/bin/sh",0
```

Comment: Hey thx for answer. No it's not working. if I execute it and say echo $0 it says "bash".