# How to pass argv arguments to execv in asm on 64-bit (linux)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system-calls, execve

I'm trying to pass arguments when invoking `/bin/bash` on a bit of 64 bit code. I cannot use the `.data` section and it's a bit tricky for me. I have looked at various code examples but none are very clear (beginner here). What I would like to invoke is `/bin/bash -c id`.

My code works when I try to leave the second argument null, but when I add it I get the following error from `strace ./test` to trace the system calls my program makes:

```
execve("/bin/bash", [0x7361622f6e69622f, 0x646920632d2068, 0x7361622f6e69622f, 0x68], NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

Compiled with: `nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm;ld -o test test.o`

```
section .text 
  global _start

_start:
  mov rax,59                     
  lea rdi,[rel bin]             
  lea rsi,[rel msg]
  syscall                       

align 8
  msg db '/bin/bash -c /bin/id',0
  bin db '/bin/bash',0
```

Comment: Nice job on a first question: you included what you're trying to do, expected behavior, actual behavior, and full code. A pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to execve is the address of an *array* of string-pointers (`char **` or `char *argv[]`). You have given it the address of a single string (`char *`).

Also [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) takes a third parameter, the environment list.  As the man page describes, argv and/or envp can be NULL, and Linux treats that as equivalent to an empty list (a valid pointer to a NULL in memory).

Here's what it should be:

```
      mov rax, 59
      lea rdi, [rel bin]
      lea rsi, [rel args]
      xor edx, edx             ; Linux accepts NULL instead of a pointer to NULL
      syscall


; section   .rodata
      align 8
args  dq bin, arg1, arg2, 0

arg1  db '-c',0
arg2  db '/bin/id',0
bin   db '/bin/bash',0
```

If you're writing shellcode, note that this contains multiple `0` bytes in both the instructions (non-negative `rel32` addressing modes and 32-bit immediates) and the data.

If you're not writing shellcode (to be extracted to a flat binary with code and data together), put your data in a separate section, preferably `.rodata` for read-only data.

Comment: In asm I would ave pushed onto the stack and passed rsp for the pointer to argv.